# Merging Duplicate Cells into One Cell -- Combining Both Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a spreadsheet that has a user form for people to input project information and time length. This information is fed into a project database spreadsheet.

This is what the Project Database looks like:

[image]

And this is what my Project Calendar looks like:
[image: Input]

This is what I'm trying to do:
[image: Output]

I'm using an =IF(ISNUMBER formula to check for "Yes" or "No" values under Q1-Q4 and it pulls the Project Name + Name into the cell field.

Now I'm wondering, for example in Row 4, Q1 and Q2 have the same value, is there a way to merge them together and have them represent the Project Name + Project across Q1 and Q2? Maybe a macro of some sort that wouldn't ruin the formulas contained in each cell?

I've been Googling around and haven't had any luck just yet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, you will need VBA to achive what you want to accomplish. There is no formula to do this. So, I suggest that you start coding and come back if you run into a specific coding problem.  You might want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so and also read [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your post with the code you have written thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script will do the work:

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

    For row = 1 To 100
        For col = 1 To 100
            If Cells(row, col) <> "" And (Cells(row, col) = Cells(row, col + 1)) Then
                Cells(row, col + 1).Value = ""
                Range(Cells(row, col), Cells(row, col + 1)).Merge
            End If
        Next col
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Added that macro to a rectangle on my form and it doesn't work. I'm researching some VBA now to get some knowledge on how to properly code but I am unsure if this is 100% applicable to my sheet. Thank you for the help though, I can probably use this as foundation once I become more familiar with VBA.

Comment: You can add this macro to a button or you can track events to check all update on your worksheet cells (Worksheet_Change) so every time you edit a cell it'll run this macro.

Comment: Could this code not be working due to the fact that my Q1-Q4 are merged cells already?

Like Q1 is merged from D-F, Q2 is merged from G-I, etc.